# Howto remove Windows 7n MachineKeys restored to alternate location?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, restore

1) I backed up a Windows 7 Pro computer to a network drive.

2) I restored all of the files to the computer, to an alternate location.
   C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Restore

3) After going through the restored files, I tried to delete the Restore folder, but get a dialog saying that Administrator permissions are needed. I grant them, then get "Folder Access Denied" because I need permissions from my account to make changes.

4) Digging around I find that I can delete everything inside Restore except:
  Restore\C\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys*

5) I'm unable to delete, rename, assume ownership, or modify permissions on the files in the MachineKeys folder.

6) Sadness and gnashing of teeth ensues.

Answer (score 1):

While writing up this question, it occurred to me to try and move the MachineKeys folder outside of the Restore folder.

This worked, and I was then able to delete the folder.

I still had to delete each folder inside Restore by hand instead of deleting the entre sub-tree in one pass, but I was able to delete them.